# openconnect VPN for all Users with individual credentials possible?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, vpn, openconnect

Hi there and thanks for reading!

I want to preset an openconnect VPN connection (gateway + cert) for all users but let each connect with their own credentials.

Here is what i have so far:

- install network-manager-openconnect-gnome (I use gnome3)
- use nmcli to add the connection:

  ```
  nmcli c a ifname "*" con-name myVPN type vpn vpn-type openconnect user-name -- ipv4.method auto ipv4.ignore-auto-routes yes vpn.persistent no vpn.data "authtype = password, gateway = myGateway.dom, cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/myCert.pem"
  ```

Connection shows up as expected, so far so good.

The Issue is that when a user tries to connect, a root password prompt comes up... if I cancel the prompt 3 times the connection credential window is shown anyway, but when valid credentials are entered and confirmed, nothing happens.
If I enter the root password, the connection is successful with the same credentials.

Is it even possible to do this with nm? Should I run a login script and create one connection per user instead?